# when i change entity colomn name i am getting error in Symfony Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have `role_type` method in my Entity and i want to change it `roleType`.
I have tried to change I am having following error.

> Notice: serialize(): "" returned as member variable from
>   __sleep() but does not exist

Comment: Have you used role_type in serialize method?

Comment: paste here serialize method.

Comment: okay paste  your entity class here where you change menthod.

Comment: Yes, show code of Roles entity class.

Comment: /**
   * @ORM\Column(name="role_type", type="string", length=255)
   */
    private $roleType;

Comment: so , you have changed name role_type to roleType. right?

Comment: Just try deleting your cache directory var/cache.  If it really is a serialization issue then doing so will clear it up.

Comment: Thanks, Its solved my problem